# How does the apt package manager decide if a package is unused?

Tags: apt

It's convenient that `apt-get` can find packages that are not in use and remove them to keep your system clean using `sudo apt-get autoremove`.

But what are the exact criteria `apt` uses to define a package as "unused"?

I'd like to use it to clean up my Ubuntu installation, but if it's speculative in some way or risks breaking shared libraries, I'd rather live in the filth of my server as is.

Comment: A more direct answer to my question based on the contents of that would be great.

Comment: Quoting Rinzwind's answer: "Whenever you install an application (using apt-get) the system will also install the software that this application depends on. It is common in Ubuntu/Linux that applications share the same libraries. When you remove the appplication the dependency will stay on your system.

So apt-get autoremove will remove those dependencies that were installed with applications and that are no longer used by anything else on the system." Seems to me it answers this question, no matter how large you make your text.

Comment: Please post as an answer and link to the original answer. Trying to read that with no formatting is virtually impossible (at least for me)

Comment: It's the only answer to the dupe I linked to in my first comment.

Comment: Still, posting as an answer (not a comment) would be easier to read

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat just look at the accepted answer for that other question. It answers your question exactly.

Comment: Ok the original duplicate link that was posted had several answers and none of them were clear. I can live with the new one that was posted in the body of my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A package will be marked as unused by apt if it meets two conditions:

1. If it was automatically installed as a dependency as another
2. No packages depend on it anymore

Excerpt from http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/apt.8.html:

> autoremove (apt-get(8))
>              autoremove is used to remove packages that were automatically
>              installed to satisfy dependencies for other packages and are now no
>              longer needed as dependencies changed or the package(s) needing
>              them were removed in the meantime.
>
> You should check that the list does not include applications you
>              have grown to like even though they were once installed just as a
>              dependency of another package. You can mark such a package as
>              manually installed by using apt-mark(8). Packages which you have
>              installed explicitly via install are also never proposed for
>              automatic removal.

Comment: Does this answer your question @Sridhar-Sarnobat

Comment: I think that's the info I was looking for. It won't tell me if some pointless CLI program I installed is in use or not. But it will find those shared libraries that I don't even realize are there, which is good.

Comment: wait, are these 2 the criteria for it appearing as removable by `apt`, or are they just widely accepted checks that a system administrator should perform?

Comment: This is what apt uses

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: If possible, could you copy the info from the documentation or manpage and link to it? I'm looking myself but I can't decide whether it covers what you're saying. That's why I'm flipping back and forth between your answer and the other one. Then your answer will be a perfect reference ;)

Comment: updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

For every installed package the package manager keeps a record of whether that package is marked "automatically installed" or not, among other metadata.

Packages installed during OS installation are never marked automatically installed.

When you install a package it may cause other packages you didn't request to be installed as well.  Those additional packages will be marked as automatically installed.

This is only a convenience feature allowing you to remove cruft you probably don't need anymore.  You do not have to take advantage of it, but if you do, you can remove any automatically installed packages that are no longer a dependency of a manually installed package with `apt-get autoremove`.